# Sort list of folders on most items in folder

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of folders that a get via

```
import glob
list_of_folders = glob.glob('path_to_folder/*')
for folder in list_of_folders:
```

Now, I want to sort list_of_folders on the amount of files that are in the folder. Something like

```
list_of_folders.sort(key= lambda f: len(x) for x in glob.glob(f))
```

But I whatever I try I can't get a valid lambda expression that works with this. How can I sort the list of folders on the amount of files in the folder?

Comment: `sorted(glob.glob('path_to_folder/*'), key=lambda d: len(os.listdir(d)), reverse=True)`

Comment: @falsetru Make your comment an answer.

Comment: @falsetru I was about to write the same thing, but you put it here (before I wrote it), so please make it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lambda d: len(os.listdir(d))` as `key` argument:

```
import glob
import os

list_of_folders = glob.glob('path_to_folder/*')
list_of_folders.sort(key=lambda d: len(os.listdir(d)), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 5):

[falsetru's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2225682/falsetru) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565750/sort-list-of-folders-on-most-items-in-folder#comment29034734_19565750):

`sorted(glob.glob('path_to_folder/*'), key=lambda d: len(os.listdir(d)), reverse=True)`

Is *almost* the correct answer, but there is one thing to consider:

If the path returned in the glob is not a directory, then `os.listdir()` will fail. To get over this we can do the following:

```
from glob import glob
import os

list_of_dirs = filter(os.path.isdir, glob('path_to_folder/*'))
list_of_dirs.sort(key=lambda d: len(os.listdir(d)), reverse=True)
```

Or we can do this one-liner:

```
sorted(glob('path_to_folder/*/'), key=lambda d: len(os.listdir(d)), reverse=True)
```

Which uses an extra `/` at the end to make sure only directories are returned, but this is slightly less stable than the first method (though it looks a bit nicer).